# Using buildr for non compilation tasks

Tags: buildr

I want to use buildr for task automation.

The feature I want to use is the `buildr cc` which (by default) runs compilation when source folder is changed.

My goal is to setup buildr for a specific directory to execute a custom task (e.g.a system call)

My latest version (not working because I define build) is the following.

```
define "directory_watcher" do
  compile.sources  << _(".")
  compile.from(_(".")).using(:javac)

  compile do
    p "Calling pandoc in compile"
    system "pandoc 0*.txt  -o directory_watcher.html -s -c css/base.css"
  end

  build do
    p "Calling pandoc in build"
    system "pandoc 0*.txt  -o directory_watcher.html -s -c css/base.css"
  end
end
```

Using this buildr file I succeeded to watch the root folder instead of main/src/...
But nothing else. If I modify a file it notifies but text "Calling pandoc in compile" is not displayed.

How to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

The continuous compilation task of Buildr determines the source files from the compiler. If the compiler is not looking for the files you change, no compilation step will occur.

If you are doing anything related to documentation, I heartily recommend using jekyll or one of those doc generators (RDoc, yard ?). Hope that helps!